# R:Table descriptive statistic: 3 variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I wonder if it's possible to get a descriptive statistics table (mean, sd and n) for 1 continuous variable by 2 categorical variables. I am looking for something that I got with Stata:

[table with stata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWSmJ.png)

I tried with `dplyr` but no success:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

mtcars%>%
group_by(carb, am)%>%
summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, n()), mpg) %>%
spread(key=am, value=mean)

# Groups:   carb [6]
  carb      sd     n   `0`   `1`
  <fct>  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1       1.93     3  20.3  NA  
2 1       5.06     4  NA    29.1
3 2       3.74     6  19.3  NA  
4 2       4.3      4  NA    27.0
5 3       1.05     3  16.3  NA  
6 4       3.00     3  NA    19.3
7 4       3.36     7  14.3  NA  
8 6     NaN        1  NA    19.7
9 8     NaN        1  NA    15
```

Comment: you could check `tabular` from `tables` or `gt`

Comment: Removed `stata` tag. If you aren't asking about Stata, it's a distraction to Stata people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ekstroem thanks for you post.

Finally I found a library that gave me a nice table:

```
library(table1)

table1(~mpg| carb*am,data = mtcars)
```

The only one problem (for me), its that output is a HTML table. I am using rtf library to export R table to word, but I dont know how export this output table (HTML) to word .

If you know how solve this, I will appreciate.
I am no using R-studio.
Regards

[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8nm7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `tableone` package can be used to create Table like tables directly from R. Here is a version that creates the same type of info as you have in the screenshot.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("tableone")

mtcars %>% 
    select(mpg, am, carb) %>% 
    CreateTableOne(data=., strata=c("am", "carb")) %>% 
    print()
```

This will produce the following output

```
                  Stratified by am:carb
                   0:1          1:1          0:2          1:2          0:3          1:3 0:4         
  n                    3            4            6            4            3        0       7       
  mpg (mean (SD))  20.33 (1.93) 29.10 (5.06) 19.30 (3.74) 27.05 (4.30) 16.30 (1.05) -   14.30 (3.36)
  am (mean (SD))    0.00 (0.00)  1.00 (0.00)  0.00 (0.00)  1.00 (0.00)  0.00 (0.00) -    0.00 (0.00)
  carb (mean (SD))  1.00 (0.00)  1.00 (0.00)  2.00 (0.00)  2.00 (0.00)  3.00 (0.00) -    4.00 (0.00)
                  Stratified by am:carb
                   1:4          0:6 1:6        0:8 1:8        p   test
  n                    3        0       1      0       1              
  mpg (mean (SD))  19.27 (3.00) -   19.70 (NA) -   15.00 (NA)  NA     
  am (mean (SD))    1.00 (0.00) -    1.00 (NA) -    1.00 (NA)  NA     
  carb (mean (SD))  4.00 (0.00) -    6.00 (NA) -    8.00 (NA)  NA
```